# Display only latest three results from PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

$result = @mysql_query('SELECT Article FROM news WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM News)');
if (!$result) {
    die('<p>Error performing query: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo('<p>' . $row['Article'] . '</p>');
}

?>
```

Basically, I need to tweak this code, so that it shows the latest three results instead of just the latest one, the newest being the first.

Answer (score 5):

in mysql query add limit

```
select * from table order by id desc limit 0,3
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with this query:

```
$result = @mysql_query('SELECT Article FROM news ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3');
```

FWIW, you may like to sort out the capitalisation of your database columns. The inconsistency will cause you problems in future.

Answer (score 1):

this query ?

```
SELECT Article FROM News ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3
```